# asp default design style appears in design time only , disappears in runtime visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

when I open a vs 2010 default website in vs 2012 or vs 2010 ,  master page design shows ok in all pages .... when run the site (Ctrl+F5) default page or any other page shows no style at all.

It's windows 2008 server 64bit, IE 11 installed , Vs 2010 and vs 2012 installed on same machine.
Design shows ok when I saved it to an .html notepad sheet and reopen it in IE 11.
If I open the site as file system it works fine. Is this something to do with the IIS User?

Answer (score 0):

Ok now I solve it ..... We need to open the server manager --->  Roles  ---> Add Role Service ---> Web Server ---> Common HTTP Features ---> Check the Static Content checkbox.

This work for me excellent.